# Assign shortcut key in WPF Ribbon Button

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a WPF Ribbon Button and I want it to have a shortcut key. (e.g. Ctrl+A). Been searching in google but lost to get a possible answer. Does anyone knows how I might deal with this? Thanks =)

**Here is what I have so far**

```
<my:RibbonButton Name="rb1" Content="Images/save.png" />
<my:RibbonButton Name="rb2" Content="Images/abort.png" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may perhaps use [UIElement.InputBindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.inputbindings(v=vs.110).aspx) with [KeyBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keybinding(v=vs.110).aspx)

example

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="S"
                Modifiers="Control"
                Command="{Binding Save}" />
    <KeyBinding Key="A"
                Modifiers="Control"
                Command="{Binding Abort}" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

using this approach you can bind the input gestures to the commands which buttons are using

assumed code

```
<my:RibbonButton Name="rb1" Content="Images/save.png" Command="{Binding Save}" />
<my:RibbonButton Name="rb2" Content="Images/abort.png" Command="{Binding Abort}" />
```

---

from [MSDN: KeyBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keybinding(v=vs.110).aspx)

> A KeyBinding associates a KeyGesture with a ICommand, such as a RoutedCommand. RoutedCommand is the primary implementation of the ICommand interface for the WPF commanding system .  In general, when the KeyGesture is executed the command is invoked, although the command behavior is further influenced by command-specific factors such as the CanExecute value.

Comment: is there any error? specially data binding error. do you have the commands in place?

Comment: No there's no error showing. It just that nothing happen whenever I type "N" or "Ctrl+N" and also tried "Alt+N".. Yieh I make sure commands are in right place same as what you posted.

Comment: here is a working sample for input bindings, download [CSharpWPF.zip](https://drive.google.com/a/ruhal.in/file/d/0B2f5wPS0jKJPTXNSdUs1V19QZWM/view), you may focus only on mainwindow & viewmodel, ignore the rest

Comment: When I tried downloading the file there are some of this saying "Sorry, you can't view or download this file at this time." Is there any way to download it?

Comment: @x'tian, there might be some temporary issues with google drive, you may download the same from this location http://pushpraj.com/share/CSharpWPF.zip

Comment: Oh no. I can't open the file. The version is unrecognized. =(

Comment: @x'tian, it is in VS2013. perhaps you may create a new project with those files, all you may need is mainwindow, viewmodel & simplecommand.

Comment: its still not opening.. =( can you just post the code here? thanks you.

Comment: I pasted to [KeyBinding in WPF sample @ pastebin](http://pastebin.com/wiSFW2G4) I hope this works for you

Answer (score 1):

I prefer doing it in code behind. I am using the code in my program.
Hope it help.

```
private void AddHotKeys()  
{
        try
        {
            RoutedCommand firstHotkey = new RoutedCommand();
            firstHotkey .InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.S, ModifierKeys.Alt));
            CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(firstHotkey , Save));


        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            //handle exception error
        }
```

}